# Why can't I read my text file?

Tags: java

I am trying to read in a text file, but I keep getting "java.util.InputMismatchException".

Main class:

```
dc.loadData(new File("DVDCollection.txt"));
```

Class that reads/loads the files data:

```
Scanner inputFile = null;
public void loadData(File fileName) {
    try {
        inputFile = new Scanner (new File("DVDCollection.txt"));
    }

    catch (Exception FileNotFoundException) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + FileNotFoundException.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {

        String fileTitle = inputFile.nextLine();
        String fileCategory = inputFile.nextLine();
        String fileRunningTime = inputFile.nextLine();
        int fileYear = inputFile.nextInt();
        double filePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();

        DVD dvdEntry = new DVD(fileTitle, fileCategory, fileRunningTime, fileYear, filePrice);
        DVDlist.add(dvdEntry);
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

The text file has one piece of information per line, with no line breaks.

Example:

```
Movie title1 (Sttring)
movie category1 (String)
movie duration1 (String)
movie year1 (int)
movie price1 (double)
Movie title2
movie category2
movie duration2
movie year2
movie price2
etc
etc...
```

And here is an actual example of what it's supposed to read in:

```
Adam
Documentary
78 minutes
2012
7.99
Choo Choo
Documentary
60 minutes
2006
11.99
```

What the error says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at XXXX_XXXX.DVDCollection.loadData(DVDCollection.java:29)
at XXXX_XXXX.DVDApplication.main(DVDApplication.java:14)
```

Comment: Show us exception message and stack trace. Try to replace the line that throws an exception with `System.out.println("Unparsable token: "+inputFile.next());` to check if scanner reads what you expect it to read. Most probably you should read line break (`inputFile.nextLine();`) after reading integer number.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid using the `Scanner` to read from files, but use a `BufferedReader` to read line by line and parse those Strings appropriately. And unless you need to treat the year and price as numbers, why not save the conversion and just leave them as `String`?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl, why would you suggest not using a `Scanner`?  Seems appropriate for what OP wants.

Comment: One of your years or prices is not able to be parsed as an `int` or `double` hence the exception claiming a type mismatch.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl, I have to use int and double for the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it will suit

```
String fileTitle = inputFile.nextLine();
String fileCategory = inputFile.nextLine();
String fileRunningTime = inputFile.nextLine();
int fileYear = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());
double filePrice = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.nextLine());
```

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it. Would you mind explaining why that is?

Comment: nextInt() does not read '\n', so nextDouble() will see '\n' instead of a double value. But that is not the case with nextLine(), it will read '\n' and returns only the other characters read, as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an issue with those lines:

```
int fileYear = inputFile.nextInt();
double filePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();
```

At some point the expected type is not found (not a double).
Make sure you go to the next line and that your file contains no errors (numbers are formatted as expected...).

Answer (score 0):

The `InputMisMatchException` (when thrown from `nextDouble()`), indicates that "the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range" (quote from [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29)).

So the problem is most likely in the file you're trying to read. Without its contents, however, it's hard to guess what exactly is the culprit.

Comment: Using `new DecimalFormat().getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()` you can find out whether your system expects the `.` as decimal separator or the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner#nextDouble()` throws `InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the `Float` regular expression, or is out of range.

So clearly the input is not a float literal. I am expecting there might be space, which makes `double` as `string`..

Answer (score 0):

From your trace shows that the `Scanner` has tried to read a value that is supposed to be `double` value is not a `double` value.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
**at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)**
at XXXX_XXXX.DVDCollection.loadData(DVDCollection.java:29)
at XXXX_XXXX.DVDApplication.main(DVDApplication.java:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for your problem.

When you use nextline() it advances the scanner past the current line and places it at the beginning of next line.

But when you use nextInt or nextDouble then the scanner is advanced just past the nextInteger and next double value and placed at the end of the current line itself.

Hence a \n is also read as part of the next nextLine breaking the sequence.

You can code like this as a work around.

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            String fileTitle = inputFile.nextLine();
            String fileCategory = inputFile.nextLine();
            String fileRunningTime = inputFile.nextLine();
            int fileYear = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());
            double filePrice = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.nextLine());
        }
        inputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add the line marked with ***
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {

    String fileTitle = inputFile.nextLine();
    String fileCategory = inputFile.nextLine();
    String fileRunningTime = inputFile.nextLine();
    int fileYear = inputFile.nextInt();
    double filePrice = inputFile.nextDouble();

    DVD dvdEntry = new DVD(fileTitle, fileCategory, fileRunningTime,
        fileYear, filePrice);
    DVDlist.add(dvdEntry);

    if (inputFile.hasNext()) //***
        inputFile.nextLine();
}
```